# UITableViewCells disappearing when scrolling on iOS 15+

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I've recently updated to Xcode Version 13.4.1 which runs iOS 15.5 simulators. I've noticed that I get the following error when running my project on iOS 15.5 simulator when loading uitableviewcells with uicollectionviews inside them.

```
[Assert] UITableView internal inconsistency: cell prefetched for IP(0,6) already stored for IP(0,5).
```

And the uitableviewcells seem to sporadically disappear when scrolling. However this doesn't occur when I run it on an iOS 13 simulator and the table view loads correctly with no issues. It seems to be occurring for uitableviewcells that contain a UICollectionView.

Here's a snippet from the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestTableViewCell") as? TestTableViewCell else {fatalError()}

        cell.collectionView.registerNibArray(withNames:["TestCollectionViewCell"])
        cell.collectionView.delegate = self
        cell.collectionView.dataSource = self
        cell.collectionView.reloadData()
        return cell
}
```

It seems to be that uitableview prefetching has changed in a recent version of iOS, any solution would be very helpful.

Comment: That's a very bad approach. You should put the collection view logic (register cells, delegate, dataSource, etc) in the cell class itself. Can't tell for sure without seeing a [mre], but that *very possibly* is causing your issues.

Comment: Does the code stop at the line of "fatalError()"?

Comment: The code in my question is just an example that you could implement yourself and test. I have put the logic in the class itself @DonMag.

Comment: @BomiChen no, the fatalError() doesn't get called. It's more of a UI issue. The code doesn't crash, it just produces strange disappearing cells.

Comment: @SamuelHinchcliffe - I think you'll need to put together a [mre]. I'm not seeing what you're describing using this basic example (running on iOS 15.5 simulator): https://gist.github.com/DonMag/de46dde832e6770967c40afd625b68bb

Comment: @DonMag is right, the collectionView.delegate needs to give the cell itself.

Comment: I had NSAttributed strings from html (NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html) inside UICollectionViewCell + UITableViewCell, which caused disappearing error from time to time. Removed NSAttributedString = no error

Comment: were u able to solve it?

Comment: able to solve it . iam also facing the same issue with xcode 13.4.1